# Right to Left in Arabic language in odoo12 in Windows OS is not working

Tags: windows, npm-install, right-to-left, odoo-12, rtlcss

I have followed the steps in odoo 12 documentation to implement rtl in odoo 12
But it is not working in Windows but it is well worked in linux OS
Help me with it!

Answer (score 0):

You seem miss install [rtlcss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rtlcss) package on windows

- First install nodeJS on Windows.
- Afterword use npm comes with node to install rtlcss package

  npm install -g rtlcss

Hope that's help.